# Can't get Python SUDS to query a code with this WSDL

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I am not getting a result when I run this.
Somehow, I think I should be getting something other than 'nothing' when I query a valid HCPCS code (the 99213 code in the 4th line below). 
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/HCPCSService.svc?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
print client
result = client.service.GetDetailsByCode('99213')
print result
```

**Question:** How can I get this to work? According to [this site,](http://www.nsmha.org/datadict/Codes/CPT.aspx) 99213 is a valid HCPCS code, but I cannot get the description or any other details from the web service using this code.
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine. It returns a class. Put in T1000 instead of 99213 and you'll see what I mean.

HCPCS codes overlap with CPT codes, except HCPCS are used by Medicare (CPT tend to be used by private insurance). It appears this WSDL only returns values for valid HCPCS Level 2 codes. 
A more precise definition of HCPCS Level 2 codes can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCPCS_Level_2). A general definition of HCPCS codes and their relationship with CPT codes can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healthcare_Common_Procedure_Coding_System).

Comment: apparently 99213 is not a valid HCPCS code. It's a valid CPT-4 code, but that's beyond the scope of the WSDL, I think.

Comment: I will then go ahead and delete all my comments, just to avoid clutter. Please delete yours as well, and thanks for providing a good answer.